# Help with proof about quotient groups

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

> Suppose $G$ and $H$ are groups, $N \triangleleft G$ and $K\triangleleft H$ are subgroups. Show that $N\times K\triangleleft G\times H$ and $(G\times H)/(N\times K)\cong(G/N)\times(H/K)$.

I was in the middle of constructing a isomorphism, but I stopped since to me it seems that $(G\times H)/(N\times K)$ is exactly $(G/N)\times(H/K)$, is it enough to show that they are equal by double containment or is an isomorphism better to do?

And if the isomorphism route is more viable, I'm stuck with

$f: (g, h) \times (N, K) \to (gN, hK)$, which is where my initial confusion stems from. I have an idea to use conjugation but I want to know whether I'm headed in the right direction, if any.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: You need to do an isomorphism.  You don't have containment in any direction because they are not subsets of the same set, for example.  And they are not quotients of the same set either.  If you feel like you could do a double containment argument, it is only because you are implicitly using an isomorphism in your head to compare them.

Comment: You are welcome for the MathJax. Please learn it for next time!

Answer (score 1):

Well, these quotients are not literally the same: the elements of $G\times H/(N \times K)$ are subsets of $G\times H$, while the elements of $(G/N)\times (H/K)$ are pairs of cosets.

I think the cleanest approach is to apply the first isomorphism theorem to $G\times H\to (G/N)\times (H/K)$.

Comment: ok then, I have that f(g, h) maps to (gN, hK) which works well enough for surjectivity and homomorphism, but I can't show at all that it is injective

Comment: It's not injective. You need to show that its kernel is exactly $N\times K$.

Comment: so is my function not going to work? or is Ker(f) = N x K an alternative to direct proof of injectivity

Comment: The first isomorphism theorem says $A/\ker f\cong\mathrm{im}\, f$ for any homomorphism $f:A\to B$. So, if you prove $\ker f=N\times K$ in our case, together with surjectivity, we are done.